# Lifetime in chained Dependency Injection

Tags: dependency-injection, asp.net-core, singleton, lifetime, transient

In .NET Core, there are three different lifetimes one can use: `Transient`, `Scoped` and `Singleton`.

Let's assume I have the following chain of depencency-injected services:

`Service A` > `Service B` > `Service C`,

meaning that `Service A` has `Service B` injected (e.g. `Service A` depends on `Service B`) and `Service B` has `Service C` injected.

Now consider `Service B` having a `Singleton` lifetime, and `Service C` having a `Transient` lifetime. Because `Service B` is a `Singleton`, it is only created once. `Service C` is `Transient`, but because `Service B` is a `Singleton`, `Service C` is still just created once as well.

Is this argumentation correct, and thus does the `Transient` lifetime I set for `Service C` not make sense? Or am I thinking wrongly here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are describing here is a common problem known as [Captive Dependency](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2014/06/02/captive-dependency/). Service C becomes captive because its consumer has a longer lifetime.

This issue is widespread and is a common source of bugs in applications that use Dependency Injection and DI containers. When an application grows, these issues can easily slip in undetected. From experience I can tell that tracing back a bug to such misconfiguration can take a lot of time.

Unfortunately, the built-in container of .NET Core does not detect and prevent these kinds of mistakes. Some of the other, more mature, DI libraries for .NET actually have these kinds of features where they detect and prevent these kinds of misconfigurations.