# For a SingletonObject, Why can I add dependency on a Transient object but not on a Scoped object in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection, azure-functions, lifetime-scoping

I am writing an Azure function and I have 2 classes Dependent and Parent. The below code shows the dependency chain. `Dependent` uses instance of `Parent` class.

```
public Dependent(Parent parent)
{
    Parent = parent;
}
```

If I set the lifetime of Parent to be transient then the code works.

```
public override void Configure(IFunctionsHostBuilder builder)
{
    builder.Services.AddTransient<Parent>();
    builder.Services.AddSingleton<Dependent>();
}
```

But if I Set the lifetime of Parent to be Scoped then I get the following error.

> [2023-09-28T11:14:54.195Z] Executed 'Function1' (Failed, Id=19772818-9385-4382-8c53-116589abb2fa, Duration=1ms)
> [2023-09-28T11:14:54.199Z] Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.WebHost: Dependency FunctionApp1.Parent {ReturnDefault} as parameter "parent" reuse CurrentScopeReuse {Lifespan=100} lifespan shorter than its parent's: singleton FunctionApp1.Dependent {ReturnDefault} #150
> [2023-09-28T11:14:54.204Z]   from scoped container with {no name}

Transient dependency is shorter than scoped but it works for Transient but not for Scoped. Why is it so ?

Comment: Well, scoped life time depends on a scope while transient depends on an instance. If you want to use a scoped object you need to create your own scope inside the singleton service.

Comment: Isn't the Azure function execution instance a Scope already ?

Comment: Nope, it's not relevant. Scopes are in the dependency injection level.

Comment: It does not make a logical sense and breaks the pattern to do what you are trying to do. Although dependency injection opens some new horizons, the singleton was never intended to have anything injected into it multiple times, Singleton's role is to load once and reuse the instance because loading multiple instance can be slow. Potential solution for you is to inject both, parent and dependent into the consuming type and in there call `singletonDependent.DoSomething(parent)`

Comment: So what I am understanding from your comments and this [SOQuestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41742984/lifetime-in-chained-dependency-injection) is that I should never use lower lifetime objects in higher lifetime objects ? Transient and Scoped should not be used within Singleton ?
If that is true then how would ILogger<T> classes be injected into Singleton objects as ILogger objects are transient ?

Comment: Microsoft Note 

Do not resolve a scoped service from a singleton and be careful not to do so indirectly, for example, through a transient service. It may cause the service to have incorrect state when processing subsequent requests. It's fine to: 

   -- Resolve a singleton service from a scoped or transient service.
    -- Resolve a scoped service from another scoped or transient service.

Comment: I want to use a scoped CorrelationId variable inside my CustomLogger code to log the CorrelationId with each log statement. So that I can just log a message and custom logger can take care of adding the CorrelationId which would be scoped to the function execution instance ? The ILogger<T> instance is transient so my CustomLogger is also Transient - how do I do that ?

Comment: you need to add @username if you write to someone, Otherwise you're talking to yourself